# Encoding clock signal into linear block codes

Tags: serial, softwareserial, wireless, virtualwire, coding-standards

In the VirtualWire library, it is possible to encode the clock signal as the library is doing with 4b/6b coding. This is possible because VirtualWire uses convolutinal coding, where the *information is spread along the sequence*. But, is the same possible for linear *block* coding, such as LDPC/Hamming?

Otherwise, if it is not possible, then how would I best deal with the signal going out of sync with serial communication, given I want to use LDPC coding.

Lastly, the reason I am using serial communication is because I will have numerous nodes in my wireless mesh network, so to my knowledge, for the sake of: speed, power efficiency, scalability, *ease of implementation*, etc, serial communication works best. But has anyone had better luck with any other types of communication that can take care of the sync problem, while accounting for speed, power efficiency, scalability, etc?

**EDIT:** The way I am doing wireless communication is by using simple rf transceivers. There will by one transceiver per node and I am trying to create a stable channel between one node to another. The communication channel isn't very reliable without some error correction. And I don't want to use the existing VirtualWire's convolutional error correction. I want to use LDPC codes, developed by Radford Neal. My goal is to first create a stable channel from one Arduino to another. Then, I will implement the network.

Comment: @Majenko Any ideas?

Comment: Are you concerned with the transmission between microcontroller and wireless radio or between nodes in the mesh? And could you elaborate on your requirement to transmit a clock signal? Wireless mesh networks normally don't need that in order to communicate.

Comment: Except of course if you intend to implement your very own protocol throughout all the OSI layers. ;)

Comment: I do actually intend to implement my very own protocol. Long road ahead. @sekdiy

Comment: Still, what part of your communication needs a self-clocked data stream (i.e. see my above question)?

Comment: Sometimes the receiver doesn't realize which bit is the start bit, and assumes one of the message bits was the start bit. The internal delay between the start bit and the message, and the internal delay between each bit of the message is different. This causes the a leakage of extra bits or loss of certain bits. Does that clarify?

Comment: Well, if you want to stream (and maybe later make your own flow control) then why not do it like in other networks before yours (like Ethernet): Manchester Code (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_code). It's been used for that purpose before (see e.g. http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=63755.0) and there even are libraries available (e.g. from Atmel). Make sure that you have a plan at what layer you have to solve which problem, though. They can't be tackled all at the same level.